# Send a Wordpress contact form with Ajax

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I'm developing a web app for my Wordpress blog and I use the [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) to retrieve the posts/categories/users etc.

All I need now is to integrate a contact form in my app. So I was wondering how to send a contact form directly with an Ajax request.

Is it possible to do this simply? In the same way that you can post a Wordpress comment with a simple Ajax request?

I am currently using the well-known [Contact Form 7](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for the contact form on my website but it does not have a REST API. I saw that there was the [Contact Form 7 to API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-to-api/) plugin but I don't think it allows to do that, or I misunderstood its usefulness. I don't mind using any other plugin

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @NewToJS I would like to, but I don't know where to start :( I'm more looking for a lead